# passing a variable a number of arguments in php

Tags: php, while-loop

I know this is kind of a noob question but can somebody explain to me what is going on in this function?

```
// Prints "hello mutated world" 
function mutator($args = null) { 
    $n = count($args); 
    while($i<$n) $args[$i++] = "mutated"; 
} 
$a = "hello"; 
$b = "strange"; 
$c = "world"; 
mutator(array($a, &$b, $c)); 
echo "$a $b $c";
```

Specifically, what are the values of `$i` and `$n`? What does `$args = null` mean and how does it fit into the while loop?

Comment: You're not passing a variable number of arguments, you're passing an array.

Comment: I see that but it does not really help me understand what's going on here. I notice the & simple next to the variable $b in the mutator array but still don't understand why it's passing mutated.

Comment: Then a good look at this page will help: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `mutator` takes an array and, within its body, it changes each element of the array to the string "mutated", and does not return anything.  Normally there would be no effect on the array passed into the `mutator` outside the context of that function, in fact, it would not be obvious that the function had done anything at all.  However, because the element `$b` is passed by reference (`&$b`), the function is able to modify it.  That is why your code will print "hello mutated world".

`$n` is set by the statement `$n=count($args);`, which returns the number of elements in the variable `$args`

`$i` is a variable which will be incremented within the while loop (`$i++`.)  Because `$n` is the number of elements in `$args`, the condition for the while loop `($i<$n)` means that the loop will run once for every element in `$args`.

`$args=null` in the function definition is just providing a default value of null for the function to use if it is called with no arguments.

---

Revisiting this answer several years later, there are a couple of things I'd like to add. I understand the function is probably just intended to illustrate the effect of passing a reference in an array as a function argument, but it's not a well-constructed PHP function, and it's easy to see why a beginner who would need to see this kind of example would have had some doubts about how it worked.

The definition should make it more obvious that it expects the argument to be an array, and the default value should be an empty array rather than `null`. In newer versions of PHP, `null` is not countable and the function would cause a warning if it was called with no arguments. After PHP 7.1, we can also show that it doesn't return anything:

```
function mutator(array $args = []): void { ...
```

Also, `$i` is undefined before being used in the while loop. In the first iteration of the loop, it will be null until it is incremented with `++`, so it will never have a value of `0`, and it won't access the first array element. You can see that by passing the first element as a reference as well; it won't be mutated. `$i` should be initialized to zero before the the loop, or a `for` loop should be used instead.

```
for ($i = 0, $n = count($args); $i < $n; $i++) {
    $args[$i] = 'mutated';
}
```

This way `$i` is defined, so there won't be any undefined variable notices, you'll be able to access the first element of `$args`, and hopefully it will be more obvious what's going on. (Although I assume this won't be that helpful to the OP five years later.)

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`func_*_args()` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php):

```
function a() {
    if (func_num_args() > 0) {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
            var_dump($arg);
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
a('one', 'two', 'three', 'and so on...');
```